# Checking when capslock is turned on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written this JQuery program for checking whenever caps lock is turned on.

```
$("input[type='password']").keypress(function(e) {
    var kc = e.which; //get keycode
    var isUp = (kc >= 65 && kc <= 90) ? true : false; // uppercase
    var isLow = (kc >= 97 && kc <= 122) ? true : false; // lowercase
    // event.shiftKey does not seem to be normalized by jQuery(?) for IE8-
    var isShift = ( e.shiftKey ) ? e.shiftKey : ( (kc == 16) ? true : false ); // shift is pressed

    // uppercase w/out shift or lowercase with shift == caps lock
    if ( (isUp && !isShift) || (isLow && isShift) ) {
        capLock(); // alerts "CAPSLOCK is ON"
    }

});
function capLock() {
 alert('CAPSLOCK is ON');
}
```

Comment: @Ethan. Your profile says you're from  Minneapolis. Your language usage says you're from Northern Ireland. (Using *whenever* for *when* is a distinctive of Norn Iron usage.)

Comment: @TRiG Hmm. Interesting. Some of my family is from Ireland, and we do have some Irish ancestry....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turning my comment on your question into an answer:

On a Mac, when the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key is engaged, the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key doesn't change the case to lower. So in the event that the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key has already been engaged, before your page even loads, this code won't work as intended. I believe this jQuery plugin has already solved this problem - [github.com/nosilleg/capslockstate-jquery-plugin](http://github.com/nosilleg/capslockstate-jquery-plugin)

---

As for your code itself:

1. I like that you've got named variables, that makes the final `if` statement super easy to read. You could name the event variable as such too, so it's clearer what `e` contains.
2. You can refactor this `var isUp = (kc >= 65 && kc <= 90) ? true : false; // uppercase`

to:

```
var isUp = (kc >= 65 && kc <= 90) // uppercase
```

because `(kc >= 65 && kc <= 90)` evaluates to a boolean value. The conditional operator is redundant.

3. Similarly, you can refactor: `var isShift = ( e.shiftKey ) ? e.shiftKey : ( (kc == 16) ? true : false );`

to:

```
var isShift = ( e.shiftKey ) || (kc == 16);
```

The interesting thing about the statement above is that it takes advantage of a mechanism called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) that boolean operators, like OR (`||`) and AND (`&&`), use.

Basically, in an OR statement, if the first expression evaluates to `true`, the second expression is never evaluated, because `true || anything` will always evaluate to `true`.

Similarly for an AND statement, if the first expression evaluates to `false`, the second expression is never evaluated, because `false && anything` will always evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Actually on a Mac, when Capslock is on, the Shift key has no effect on whether the letters are lowercase, the result will always be uppercase. This happens on Windows platforms however.

Comment: @James huh interesting. I could swear I typed "doesn't change", I just copy pasted my comment from before which has disappeared. Thanks for pointing that out, edited my answer.

Comment: @Vidur that looks clean and easy to understand i will incorporate that one on my current code